# A question in proof of Section - Transpose of Linear Transformation in Hoffman Kunze Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

While studying Linear Algebra from Hoffman and Kunze I have a question in a proof

It's image :
[image]

> My question is in 2nd last line of proof. I think in summation limit of i should be 1 to m instead of 1 to n as in the equation in last fifth line limit is i=1 to m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous line should be $f = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\alpha_i) \, f_i$. With this, it is correct that
\begin{align}
T^t(g_j) &= \sum_{i=1}^n [T^t(g_j)](\alpha_i) f_i = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ji}f_i
\end{align}

Comment: Good point. I had not even seen that typo.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not correct. We have that $T : V \to W,$ where $\dim V = n$ and $\dim W = m.$ Observe that the transpose $T^t : \operatorname{Hom}_k(W, k) \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(V, k)$ takes a linear functional on $W$ to a linear functional on $V,$ hence an element in the image of $T^t$ can be written in terms of the $n$ elements in a basis of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V, k).$ **Edit:** as @peek-a-boo points out, there is a typo in the second-to-last displayed equation of the proof. Particularly, the upper limit of the sum should be $n.$